ScrollTop=ScrollHeight with angular 17 and signal change detection
i'm currently trying to build a chatApp with angular 17.3 that interact with ollama backend. While using the last signal models feature. I manage to bind the signals properly and trigger signal change, but i'm unable to asign the scrollTop balue to scrollHeight in order to automaticaly scroll down on nex messages :
chat.component.ts :
export class ChatComponent {
  
  inputMessage: string = ''; 
  messages = model<Message[]>([]);
 

  constructor( 
    private messageIdService: MessageIdServiceService,
    private chatService: ChatService
  ) {
    //addind some entry inside messages

  }

  sendInputMessage() {
    const message: Message = {
      "id": this.messageIdService.generateUniqueId(),
      "role": "user",
      "content": this.inputMessage,
    };
    this.pushMessage(message);
    this.inputMessage = '';
    this.chatService.postChat(message).subscribe((data) => {
      data.id = this.messageIdService.generateUniqueId();
      this.pushMessage(data);
    });
  }

  pushMessage(message: Message) {
    this.messages.update(values => {
      return [...values, message];
   });
  }

}

chat.component.html :
<div id="chat">
    <div class="messageList">
      <app-message-list [(messages)]="messages"/>
    </div>
    <div class="messageInput">
      <app-message-input [(inputMessage)]="inputMessage" (sendButtonClicked)="sendInputMessage()"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  

message-list.component.ts :
export class MessageListComponent{

  messages = model<Message[]>([]);
  @ViewChild('messageList') messageList!: ElementRef;
  
  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      console.log(`New changes in messages: ${this.messages()}`);
      this.messageList.nativeElement.scrollTop  = this.messageList.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
      console.log(this.messageList.nativeElement.scrollTop , this.messageList.nativeElement.scrollHeight)  
    });
  }
}

message-list.component.html
<div #messageList class="messageList">
    @for (message of messages(); track message.id) {
        <div class="messageBox sent" *ngIf="message.role=='user'">
            {{message.content}}
        </div>
        <div class="messageBox received" *ngIf="message.role=='assistant'">
            {{message.content}}
        </div>
    } 
</div>     

i'm able to log both ScrollTop & ScrollHeight value but the assignation (ScrollTop = ScrollHeight) isn't working
console log :

Angular is running in development mode.
message-list.component.ts:19 New changes in messages: [object Object],[object Object]
message-list.component.ts:21 0 107
core.mjs:29869 Angular hydrated 4 component(s) and 29 node(s), 0 component(s) were skipped. Learn >more at https://angular.io/guide/hydration.
message-list.component.ts:19 New changes in messages: [object Object],[object Object],[object >Object]
message-list.component.ts:21 0 155
message-list.component.ts:19 New changes in messages: [object Object],[object Object],[object >Object],[object Object]
message-list.component.ts:21 0 424
message-list.component.ts:19 New changes in messages: [object Object],[object Object],[object >Object],[object Object],[object Object]
message-list.component.ts:21 0 473
message-list.component.ts:19 New changes in messages: [object Object],[object Object],[object >Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
message-list.component.ts:21 0 705

assigne scrollTop = scrollHeight
